# Why am I getting an error on calling getIndex(cell: TableViewCell1) function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am trying to get the `indexpath` of a cell for which I am using this function in my view controller.

```
func getIndex(cell : TableViewCell1) -> IndexPath
    {
       let x = cell.cellTextField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: x)
        return indexPath!
    
    }
```

It works fine, but when I try to use the value returned by this function into my IBAction method:

```
  @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
let indexPath1 = getIndex(cell: TableViewCell1)
    }
```

I am getting this error

> Cannot convert value of type 'TableViewCell1.Type' to expected argument type 'TableViewCell1'.

Need help regarding this. Pardon me if it is very basic question as I am begginer in swift.

Comment: No ,i do not have a variable name like TableviewCell1 .I am unable to find what should i pass as argument in order to call the mentioned function and get the indexpath.

Comment: The parameter `cell` must be a cell (an instance), not the type. By the way geometry math to determine the index path is one of the worst ways. The *swiftiest* way is a callback closure.

Comment: getIndex function need an instance of TableViewCell1 but you pass a class typeTableViewCell1

Comment: Oh,my bad. basically i have tried another way to get indexpath using 'tag' of cell in custom tableview cell like this : func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Int{
        let row = cellTextField.tag
        return row
    }.But i am unable to use in the viewcontroller's action method for getting indexpath for row.Will you please help me regarding this @vadian

Comment: How can i create instance of Tableviewcell1 to be passed in the function for the same.@aiwiguna

Comment: Please see this related answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60768765/is-there-a-simple-way-to-delete-specific-custom-cells-from-a-uitableview/60769027#60769027

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that method gets an object which is a type of TableViewCell1 but you give instead a type definition.

If the method tapButton is inside of subclass of TableViewCell1 then

```
class TableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {
    @IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let indexPath1 = getIndex(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer.But my tapButton method is outside subclass of TableviewCell1 as it is out of TableView .Will you please suggest me some way so that i can call the mentioned method in this function in my scenario for getting indexpath.